# Javascript object not setting image to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas

I am working on a HTML5 game and I have a function that should load an image and append it to an array for later displaying to a canvas. The code for the loading function is here...

```
function loadImage(url) {
    box.images.total++;
    image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = function () {
       box.images.loaded++;
   };
   box.images[box.images.length] = image;
}
```

The code for the holding array is here...

```
var box = new Object({});
box.images = new Array([]);
```

And the rendering code is here...

```
loadImage("images/background.png");
while (box.images.loaded<box.images.total) {console.log("lol");}
box.ctx.drawImage(box.images[0], 0, 0);
```

My hope was that this would attempt to load the set of images and would increase the counter each time. Then when an image loads it would increase the loaded counter and then once all of the code has run the rest of the code would run. But I get an error saying "function was found that matched the signature provided" and the array appears to contain an empty element.

Also i'm in Chrome on Xubuntu 12.04

**Update** It turns out that the image was being put in index 1 not 0 and that was why the image wasn't loading. But it still doesn't render the image please help.

**Another Update** So it turns out that both total and loaded were NaN and so the while loop wasn't able to load at all. I set them to zero and the wile loop didn't terminate and it crashed my browser tab.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use a while loop since it will lock up the browser and generates that "this script is taking too long" message

Comment: Thank you @soktinpk, would onload work instead?

Comment: I just checked document.onload doesn't work.

Comment: No, you need some sort of Promise or a callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some sort of `Promise` or a callback function. For simplicity, I would suggest the callback. Example:

```js
var box = {};
box.images = [];
box.images.total = box.images.loaded = 0;

function loadImage(url, callback) {
 box.images.total++;
    image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
     box.images.loaded++;
        // We call something when the image has loaded
        callback();
    };
    image.src = url;
    box.images[box.images.length] = image;
}
function loadAllImages(urls, callback) {
 // Loop through each image and load url
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; ++i) {
      var url = urls[i];
      loadImage(url, function() {
          // When everything loads, call callback
          console.log(box.images.total, box.images.loaded);
          if (box.images.loaded === box.images.total) callback();
      });
    }
}


window.onload = function() {
  box.ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
  loadAllImages([
 "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-rNTjTbBztCY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAFM/RNwjnkgQ9eo/photo.jpg?sz=128",
    "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/20e068dd2ad8db5e1403ce6d8ac2ef99?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"
  ], function() {
      // Do whatever once everything has loaded
      box.ctx.drawImage(box.images[0], 0, 0);
  });
};
```

```html
<canvas>
</canvas>
```

Comment: image.src should be set after defining onload

Comment: @soktinpk, I tried that and I got an error saying "Url is not defined" for the the line that defines loadImage.

Comment: @EliasLawson-Fox Specifically which line? What exactly does the error message say?